# running cronjobs from plesk

Tags: linux, cron

I have Plesk (or more accurately Parallels Small Business Panel) installed on my linux server. However, my knowledge of linux is pretty limited. I am trying to set up a cronjob that will run a php file.

I have found the scheduled tasks area in plesk and filled in the details for when i want the script to run e.g. 30 9 * * *. However I seem to be having difficulty writing the correct command. I am using:

usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/httpdocs/admin/file_to_run.php

I have checked that the location of php is correct using:

whereis php

I have also checked that the path to the file is correct using:

find / -name 'file_to_run.php'

However the php page is not doing it's job at the specified time. Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities

1) Check if the script has an error by doing a dry run on the command line. 
Because you will not see this error when the cron user runs the command.

2)  Perhaps you want the output to go to a specific file?

You can redirect it as such :

```
usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/httpdocs/admin/file_to_run.php > /your/destination/the_output
```

Unless your php script handles everything it needs on the inside, that is.

Comment: my php script updates a mysql database with the latest currency exchange rates. usually i would just run it in a browser. however it is not working with cron.

Comment: i have tried typing the command usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/httpdocs/admin/file_to_run.php into my SSH program (putty) but it does not appear to do anything. the mysql table is not updated.

Comment: yes, so if running this command in putty doesn't work, then that has to be resolved before cron would be able to do anything

Comment: when you say you run this from your browser, do you mean that you run  `/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/httpdocs/admin/file_to_run.php` from your browser, or that you run this by going to `http://localhost/admin/file_to_run.php` in your browser?

Comment: Because then it could be a permissions issue, since in the second case, your web server has permissions to execute this php script.

Comment: Or did you used to execute this by going to `http://mywebsite.co.uk/admin/file_to_run.php` ?